# WPF ListView handle single and double click differently

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a list view with some items, and a Style that specifies that when an item is clicked, the IsSelected property will change. See an excerpt of the code below.

Currently this selects/highlights an item and performs an action related to that item when clicked on in the list. Now I want to change the behaviour so that this happens on double click instead of single click. In addition, when an item is single clicked, that item should also be selected/highlighted, but the action related to that item is not performed, so that the user can select several items by single clicking them (similar to how you would do ctrl-click usually) and then performing all actions at once when the desired items are selected and some button clicked.

I should also mention that I am using the MVVM pattern, so there is no code in the code-behind file. Any code would go in the ItemListViewModel.cs file.

I suspect I would have to use `Command` in some way? I also found an attribute for ListView called `MouseDoubleClick=""`, however this would not replace the single click functionality, only come in addition to it.

Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ItemsList" 
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
                  VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" 
                  ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredItems}"
                  SelectionMode="Extended">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" >
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
 </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the selection behavior, take a look at [SelectionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.selectionmode). You can set `ListView.SelectionMode` to `Multiple`, which sounds like the behavior you're describing.

For the double-click, you can use the `MouseDoubleClick` event, or you can try using a [MouseBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mousebinding) which lets you use `ICommand`s instead of events (the page on [InputBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputbinding) has some good examples).

You'll have to test to see how everything plays together, though. Handling both single and double click can be tricky, and you might be forced to handle the `PreviewMouseDown` event and do everything manually (worst case scenario).

Comment: Thank you. I put the double click thing on pause for now. However I'm trying to change the behaviour of shift-click and ctrl-click. At the moment, single clicking an item displays that item in a window. This is desired. I then want to choose several items by either shift-clicking or ctrl-clicking and then showing them all at once when clicking another button. However, the item is instantly displayed in the window when I ctrl-click also, because the application registers a regular left click, in addition to the ctrl-click. How can I remove the single click behaviour from the ctrl-click?